# ListView: отображение заголовка и данных в зависимости от типа объекта

Tags: c#, wpf, listview, mvvm

В зависимости от действий пользователей в одной и той же области окна нужно отображать таблицу данных из коллекции различных типов. Т.е. в одном случае привязывать к ListМiew  одну коллекцию в другом другую. Предполагаю, что это возможно сделать создав два datatemplate указав в них тип для отображаемых данных, но не вполне понимаю как в шаблоне прописать отображение и заголовка и саму привязку к свойству объекта коллекции.

Comment: По формулировке Вашего вопроса сложно дать конкретные советы. Путей несколько. Можно, как Вы сами и пишите через `DataTemplate` можно триггерами воспользоваться, а можно просто переключать контекст данных. Нужно больше конкретики

Comment: Эм. А что нужно уточнить? Есть к примеру класс people со свойствами firstname lastname и пр. И допустим класс book имеющий свойства id, title, date и пр. И вот хочется чтобы когда привязывается коллекция с людьми он отображал заголовки имя фамилия, а когда book тайтл и дату выпуска. Хочу создать два DataTemplate для каждого типа, но смутно представляю как должен выглядеть этот код. Т.е. допустим когда создаю шаблон для treeview или ListBox, просто указываю к чему привязать TextBlock text, а как поступить тут? Как указать, что должно отображаться в header и в ячейке?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Одна и та же область окна не означает, что в ней должен отображаться один и тот же контрол.

Поскольку вы упомянули MVVM в тегах, вот вам верный дизайн с точки зрения MVVM:

1. В зависимости от действий пользователя, создайте VM нужного типа с данными, которые нужно отобразить. Пусть, например, у вас это будет один из типов `FirstVM`, `SecondVM`, `ThirdVM`. `FirstVM` пусть содержит коллекцию элементов типа `FirstItemVM` (и, возможно, другие данные), `SecondVM` — коллекцию элементов типа `SecondItemVM` и т. д.
2. Создайте `UserControl`'ы, умеющие отображать каждую из ваших VM.

   ```
   <UserControl x:Class="YourViewNamespace.FirstPresentation" ...>
       <ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding FirstItems}">
           <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
               <DataTemplate TargetType="{x:Type src:FirstItemVM}">
                   <!-- тут шаблон для отображения элемента кооллекции первого типа -->
               </DataTemplate>
           </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
       </ItemsControl>
   </UserControl>
   ```
3. Объявите в том месте, где вам нужно отображение, `DataTemplate`'ы для нужных типов, и виртуализируйтесь через `ContentPresenter`:

   ```
   <Grid>
       <Grid.Resources>
           <!-- для типа FirstVM в качестве отображения используется FirstPresentation -->
           <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type src:FirstVM}">
               <view:FirstPresentation/>
           </DataTemplate>
           <!-- для типа SecondVM -- SecondPresentation -->
           <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type src:SecondVM}">
               <view:SecondPresentation/>
           </DataTemplate>
           <!-- а для типа ThirdVM -- ThirdPresentation -->
           <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type src:ThirdVM}">
               <view:ThirdPresentation/>
           </DataTemplate>
       </Grid.Resources>
       <!-- здесь DataContext -- один из `FirstVM`, `SecondVM`, `ThirdVM` -->
       <ContentPresenter Content="{Binding}"/>
   </Grid>
   ```

Всё!

Comment: Уточните пожалуйста: каким образом правильно отображать элемент по средствам ContentPresenter? Т.е. есть у меня DataTemplate, в нем ListView привязанный к коллекции элементов, в нем GridView с коллекцией столбцов. Если я присваиваю этот DataTemplate к свойству ComtentTemplate элемента ContentPresenter, то он отображает ListView, но у  GridView просто вызывает ToString().

Comment: @КонстантинГалиахметов: Ну, идея в том, что `DataTemplate` умеет показывать список нужного типа. Внутри `FirstPresentation`, например, `ItemsControl` с `ItemTemplate`, который умеет показывать нужный тип элемента.